# NullPointerException when trying to add a TextView to a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm trying to populate a RelativeLayout with multiple elements by using a `for loop` in which a string array is the changing factor. Errors made me trim this down to a simpler code, which is still giving me trouble. I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to add the TextView, t.

```
int addGradeTypesLayoutId = R.id.AddGradeTypesLayout;

         TextView t = new TextView(this.getActivity());
         RelativeLayout addGradeTypesLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.getActivity().findViewById(addGradeTypesLayoutId);
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
         tLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);;
         t.setText("helloooo");
         t.setLayoutParams(tLayoutParams);
         t.setId(1);
         addGradeTypesLayout.addView(t);  //Exception here
```

This code runs within a fragment class in an activity.

Stacktrace as per request:

```
04-08 20:37:59.235: D/(2413): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb84b56b0, tid 2413
04-08 20:37:59.415: W/EGL_emulation(2413): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-08 20:37:59.425: D/OpenGLRenderer(2413): Enabling debug mode 0
04-08 20:38:16.135: D/dalvikvm(2413): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 121K, 7% free 3018K/3236K, paused 68ms, total 72ms
04-08 20:38:16.285: D/AndroidRuntime(2413): Shutting down VM
04-08 20:38:16.285: W/dalvikvm(2413): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a9bba8)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413): Process: com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro, PID: 2413
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro/com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro.AddCourse}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro.AddCourse.onCreate(AddCourse.java:43)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     ... 11 more
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro.AddCourse$AddCourseFragment.onCreateView(AddCourse.java:184)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1093)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1195)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
04-08 20:38:16.335: E/AndroidRuntime(2413):     ... 24 more
04-08 20:38:19.565: I/Process(2413): Sending signal. PID: 2413 SIG: 9
```

ANSWER: My fragment class (where this code runs) has a rootView defined by its layout. The fix was changing to `rootView.findViewById(addGradeTypesLayoutId)`.

Comment: @NSouth: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: *AddGradeTypesLayout* is on Fragment's layout or Activity's layout? BTW, not related but you have `;;` after *addRule* method..

Comment: @ChuongPham I've posted the stacktrace.
@Fllo _AddGradeTypesLayout_ is in the fragments layout. Thanks for the heads up about the `;;`

Comment: Did you set a layout inside your Fragment as `setContentView(R.layout.my_fragment_layout);` before add dynamically your textview into `onCreateView` of your fragment?

Comment: Look at your `AddCourse` class at line 184. This line is returning null.

Comment: @Fllo No I didn't and it looks like I can't. It wont' let me make that static call from within `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your code called Activity.setContentView() before the code you provided above.
2. If so, make sure the view or the layout that you passed to setContentView() actually contains a `RelativeLayout` with a `AddGradeTypesLayout` ID.
3. If the snippet is in onCreateView(), you should not assume that the Activity layout is ready for you to add to directly, since onCreateView() is called *before* the Activity is completely created. Instead, you should: (a) update your layout XML to specify that the fragment is inside the AddGradeTypesLayout RelativeLayout, and (b) have your onCreateView() return the new TextView [instead of calling addView() on the activity's layout object, which could be null]. [Here is an example](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Fragments_in_Android_-_A_Worked_Example#Adding_the_Fragments_to_the_Activity) of this approach (look for the **TextFragment**).

Comment: My activity's `OnCreate` sets the content view to its layout file, which then inflates the fragment's layout, which contains `AddGradeTypesLayout'. Eclipse even has it in the dropdown when I type "R.id."

Comment: Which Fragment method contains the code snippet you provided?

Comment: the code is from the Fragment's `OnCreateView` method.

Comment: onCreateView() is called *before* its Activity has been fully created. onCreateView() is supposed to return the View that the Activity will use, but it should not assume that its Activity is fully created yet. onActivityCreate() is called *after* the Activity has been fully created, but it may not be a good place to put your snippet, because then the UI will be updated while the user could be looking at it -- causing a flicker.

Comment: So, I would recommend that you change your Activity layout to specify that the fragment goes inside the AddGradeTypesLayout RelativeLayout view. See my updated answer.

Comment: So you think I'm running into a case where I'm trying to access part of the activity that hasn't been created? How then should I change my approach? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My fragment is actually not inside my RelativeLayout. My relative layout is 3 layers deep in my fragment and.... and I just figured it out. My fragment class has a rootView defined by its xml. I changed my code to rootView.findViewById(addGradeTypesLayoutId) and I'm back in business. Thanks for leading me to the answer. This is my first app, so I'm sure I'm messing up a few standards.

Answer (score -2):

You should use findViewById() to find id of the textView.